# Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/bsicMttpBinding' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, binding

I have this error from production service but it is working fine in staging and development server.

Error:

Configuration binding extension 
'system.serviceModel/bindings/bsicMttpBinding' could not be found. Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is spelled correctly

.Net Version: 4.6.1

Web.config

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
  </system.web>
```

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="http://xx/SISL.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISISL" contract="SISLReference.ISISL"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_ISISL" />
</client>
```

```
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISISL" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="16384000" maxBytesPerRead="4096000" maxNameTableCharCount="16384000" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: bsicMttpBinding - it looks like you do indeed have a typo somewhere!

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Please check the Services section of the server configuration instead of the client. In my opinion, it indeed make a typo.